# BootstrapMethodError(IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter count: 256) on lambda with 254 outside local variable references

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, invokedynamic

External variable references from Java lambdas are given as constructor arguments.
Java also allows up to 255 arguments to be given to a method.

For example, compiling this code:

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    var message = "Hello world!";
    var thread = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(message));

    thread.run();
    thread.join();
  }
}
```

And, javac generates this code:

```
final class Main$$Lambda$1 implements java.lang.Runnable {
  private final String arg$1;

  private Main$$Lambda$1(String arg1) {
    super();
    this.arg$1 = arg1;
  }

  public void run() {
    Main.lambda$main$0(this.arg$1);
  }
}
```

Then, I tried to use 255 external local variables to be referenced from the lambda.

But when I ran it, it threw a BootstrapMethodError(caused by IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter count 256)

I understood that the reason this error was thrown was because the constructor was automatically given its own object as an argument, and consequently 256 arguments were given to the constructor.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter count 256
        at Main.main(Main.java:260)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter count 256
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newIllegalArgumentException(MethodHandleStatics.java:167)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodType.checkSlotCount(MethodType.java:223)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodType.insertParameterTypes(MethodType.java:437)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodType.appendParameterTypes(MethodType.java:461)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:256)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:233)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:218)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:227)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:108)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodCommon(MethodHandles.java:4004)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodNoSecurityManager(MethodHandles.java:3960)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectMethodForConstant(MethodHandles.java:4204)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:4152)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:615)
        ... 1 more
```

Next, I created a lambda that references 254 external local variables.
When I ran this, the same error was thrown again.
Butthe number of arguments given to the constructor is 254 + 1, which should be 255.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:315)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:281)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:271)
        at Main.main(Main.java:259)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad parameter count 256
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newIllegalArgumentException(MethodHandleStatics.java:167)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodType.checkSlotCount(MethodType.java:223)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodType.insertParameterTypes(MethodType.java:437)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:259)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:233)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:218)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.preparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:227)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.makeAllocator(DirectMethodHandle.java:142)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.make(DirectMethodHandle.java:133)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectConstructorCommon(MethodHandles.java:4122)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.getDirectConstructor(MethodHandles.java:4106)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findConstructor(MethodHandles.java:2751)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:269)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:341)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:134)
        ... 4 more
```

I also rewrote var to the proper type and tried running it in java8, but got the same error.

Why did I get an error saying that 256 arguments were given?

This question has been translated from Japanese using a translator and I have based on [this article](https://qiita.com/YujiSoftware/items/31c91ff98b40fd4394f2).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lambda references outside local variables it needs to capture those at lambda creation time. The JVM dynamically creates a for this and also dynamically creates a constructor for this class. The constructor has as arguments the instance of the lambda, the captured local variables and an extra `MemberName` parameter (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/DirectMethodHandle.java#L256).

This hidden extra parameter is the reason for the exception.

---

Actually, this `MemberName` parameter is added first to the parameter list. This is the reason that your first example fails on the line `DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:256)` if you try to use a lambda with 255 captured local variables.

In the case with 254 captured local variables adding this `MemberName` parameter works and the code fails when it tries to insert the lambda instance at position 0 in the line `DirectMethodHandle.makePreparedLambdaForm(DirectMethodHandle.java:259)`

Comment: Thanks sir. My questions were solved.